# Validate smtpHost:port string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble to write regex to validate and group the bellow:

- c1dev01         --> valid
- c1dev01:25      --> valid
- 192.168.2.3     --> valid
- 192.168.2.3:189 --> valid
- c1dev01:        --> valid
- c1dev01:aa      --> not valid

Comment: @"(?<smtpHost>\w+):*(?<port>\d$)

Comment: This should generally be included in the question to show your own effort and that you are not asking us to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the validation of the correct range is best not done in regex, but in a separate step. However, regex is great to validate the string format and extract the port number in one go. For the format we can require at most one colon and only digits to the right of it (at most 5). This corresponds to the following pattern string:

```
@"^([^:]+)(?:[:](\d{0,5}))?$"
```

Where ^ and $ anchor the pattern to the beginning and end of the string. If you use this pattern in Regex.Match(), you can find the host name in match.Groups[1].Value and the port number in match.Groups[2].Value, to check that it's not more than 65535.

Of course, you can further restrict the allowed characters for the host.

Comment: Thanks but Group[0] returns the complete string .... and i need only the host name.

Comment: Wrap the host in parentheses, too. Then Group[1] will be the host. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

^(?(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})|(\w+))(:(?\d{0,5}))*$

To get the host/IP use `match.Group["host"]` and to get the port use `match.Group["posrt"]`.